# JPA: dynamic queries with ResultSet-like access / SQL-JPA?

Tags: java, jpa, jdbc

Preliminitaries: the Code lives inside a Java-Webapp which uses JPA and is happy with it, so a complete switch away from JPA is no solution.

But my part is about dynamic data queries. Let's say for example that admins can write sql queries which users can fire to produce csv-exports.

With JDBC I get a lot of metadata about the ResultSet, and I can fetch Strings and Integers where I know about them.

JPA allows direct SQL Querying, but I can fetch those only with `getResultList()` as a `List<Object>`, which is really either a `List<Object[]>` or `List<Object>` depending on the column count of the select (as far as I understood) and gives some ugly warnings on casting `List<Object>` to `List<Object[]>`.

I do understand that JPA in general can not provide a `ResultSet` or a JDBCConnection, since it could be an access to text or Big Data or memcache instead of SQL. But I have not found something like SQL-JPA.

It would be wrong and very dirty to use direct and specific methods of EclipseLink in a JPA-Application. I can be sure that the Application will stay on SQL, but not that it will stay on EclipseLink.

So it seems I do have to write a ResultSet myself, with metadata like columncount and names of columns, and I can not read the data types of the columns out of the database result. But writing a ResultSet class besides JPA which memorizes a part of the information from the SQL-String feels also wrong.

Opening an extra JDBC-Connection right inside a JPA-Application would seem to solve the problem, but I don't even get the connection data out of JPA, and two separate configurations will sooner or later lead into doom.

Is it that my use case is too strange or that JPA is too limited or am I just blind to the right solution?

SQL *is* a very powerful and simple language for complex data relations, so I wonder why JPA is soo afraid of it (of course, the tons of typical Object-Write and Object-Read were too painfull with jdbc).

Does anyone know an existing ResultSet-Implementation for JPA, or is there any right solution which I can't see?

Thanks for any help out there.

Comment: Then imagine that the end-user clicks some values together which are translated to a dynamic SQL Query by program. Data Requests are in general a bit more flexible than "I have an object `person` with name, city and birthdate", so I have no fixed object. I could define the columns of the result as objects or classes, but I see no way to read different objects in one JPA request

Comment: Could it be an option in your application to first declare a datasource and use that datasource in your JPA configuration (eg a jndi datasource) ?

Comment: @Serge, thanks for the hint. But since I have just a little corner in a complete application, that would feel very strange. I get the impression that normally no dynamic parts are involved in JPA-Applications... But maybe I am just wrong at some point. If we would define that jdi datasource, would we have access to that datasource from JPA or would we have to pass that datasource through the whole program?

Comment: If you have a datasource, you can have JPA use it (and all your application will keep using JPA) and have special parts use it at JDBC level. It is in fact a common optimisation use case : most of the code uses an ORM such as JPA, and some bottleneck parts use JDBC.

Comment: So the jdbc connection is handled "outside" JPA, nevertheless used inside JPA too. I will discuss that with the team, thanks for the hint. That means an extra channel is needed to give the JDBC-connection to my classes, whereas JPA just does `JPA.em()`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because I have seen only comments, I will try to provide an answer, but as the question does not have a very specific programming problem, my answer will be alike.

JPA is an ORM, meaning it maps database things to Java objects and provides some more features around that (transactions, translating `EntityManager` operations to SQL queries, named queries, ...). Because ORM by definition is a layer above JDBC, it does not have the purpose you need.

You are right:

- in **JPA 1.0** there is no standard way of getting a JDBC Connection from an `EntityManager` instance, and although it is not nice, it is also not so dirty as you might think: make a single static method that returns the JDBC connection from an EntityManager and that will be the only dirty place. If you will switch to Hibernate, you will change a few lines only.
- But in **JPA 2.0** there is a JPA specific way:

  `Connection conn = em.unwrap(Session.class).connection();`

  You should be in a JPA transaction to access the Connection this way. Otherwise, you will be responsible for releasing the connection. (quoted from [here](http://wiki.eclipse.org/EclipseLink/Examples/JPA/EMAPI#Getting_a_JDBC_Connection_from_an_EntityManager))

Alternatively use regular JPQL queries for retrieving all your needed data, and then you will get directly the right types. The limitation here is: it is not so flexibile as SQL, but far (e.g you can use JOIN ON from JPA 2.1).

Comment: Thanks for that conclusion. If I combine the request as JPQL, I still need a class wich has all possible result fields as members (one object = one data row) and I have no way to write the column types as classes. The idea to wrap the provider specific code is of course a good idea, probably most big SQL-providers do have that connection access.

Comment: @flaschenpost I have added probably important details on how to get a JDBC connection from an `EntityManager` in JPA 2.0.

Comment: Thanks, I think I have already tried that but it might have been before I knew about `@Transactional`. I'll give it a try.

Comment: Elder versions of Hibernate do definitely support it (but may be newer). There are many ways to open a transactions, between them is that with @Transactional, in which case one transaction is opened automatically for you (if that is an public method). Did you try with Hibernate or EclipseLink?

Answer (score 2):

If I understood you correctly, what you need is a native SQL query (which you can use with JPA) and then put the result into some data structure to operate with but without the necessity to map that beforehand within a entity, right?

Then the [Query Language Result Mapper (QLRM)](http://simasch.github.io/qlrm/) project may be of use for you, since it allows you to create the result objects from the native query with the only requirement of having the same number and types for arguments:

```
Query q = em.createNativeQuery("SELECT ID, NAME FROM EMPLOYEE");
List<EmployeeTO> list = jpaResultMapper.list(q, EmployeeTO.class);
```

If you really don't know something about the results coming in, because they are generic, then you don't have much choice than using plain JDBC and check the meta-data.

But keep in mind, that letting the user build up their own generic queries is potentially dangerous, as things like [SQL injection](http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL-Injection) may happen. Better try to define a number of possible building blocks (using prepared statements and bind variables instead of String-concatenated SQL) which you can test individually and let the user choose from that.

Comment: Almost right. I do not know at compile time which fields will be read, but simply show them like in a html table or a csv result. For your example I would need to know the result columns at compile time, because I have to define EmployeeTo with data types.